# Firefox doesn't recognize hover

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, menu, hover

I am trying to implement a pure-CSS popup context menu and have it working reasonably well in Chrome, but FireFox has me stumped. I can open the menu by focusing the button. But cursor and hover effects that work in Chrome don't in Firefox . It's visible, but Firefox is acting like it's not.

I have a jsfiddle demonstrating it is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jeffmarston/j1c9x9mL/

The key is the following CSS:

```
nav button:focus nav {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #b0e0e6;
  transition: none;
}
```

The first selector makes the nav visible when the button is focused.
The second *should* change the background color when an item is hovered, but only works in Chrome.

Comment: Hm, you have <a> elements inside the <button>s. That's not very semantic.

Comment: I guess it's not very semantic. I moved it outside and got it working. It makes sense that interacting with elements inside a button wouldbe problematic. Thanks, Mr. Lister!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the nav outside the button element did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For a clicked button to receive a `:focus` sudo class is not a standard yet in all browsers.

Check it on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) for more info.

You can jump to "Clicking and focus" section.